# finding the inverse function of $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: functions

find the inverse function of $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ where $f(x) =x+\frac{1}{x}$.

I have tried raising to the power of $2$ but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe try to use some LaTeX next time, it's not difficult :)

Comment: Agreed with @Lullaby; I edited your post Lynn. Check the edit so you know for future reference how to LaTeX your posts :) Also, there is some confusion on whether or not you want the inverse of $\frac{x+1}{x}$ or $x+\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: thank you.I'm new to this site so I'm still discovering the techniques.I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko with regards to your comment $x+\frac{1}{x}$ has no inverse, check Mark's answer below to see how you would find the inverse.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Granted, we have to be a bit careful in breaking up the domain for it to work as an inverse. But if OP really is interested in the inverse of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $\frac{x+1}{x}$, that is the closest we can get.

Answer (score 2):

Write $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Multiply by $x$ and rearrange to get $x^2 -yx +1 =0$. Now you can use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$y = \frac{x+1}{x} = 1 + \frac1x$

Thus

$ x = 1 + 1/y$

$=> y = \frac{1}{x-1}$